# Who first proved Rota' conjecture

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

In Wikipedia in article about Rota's conjecture it is written: “ A proof of the conjecture has been announced by Geelen, Gerards, and Whittle” . In Quanta magazine in article about mathematician June Huh  by KEVIN HARTNETT “A Path Less Taken to the Peak of the Math World” ,it is declared that Rota’ conjecture is proved by Adiprasito, Huh and Katz
Can somebody in this community explain who has the priority

Comment: Are we sure that [Rota's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rota%27s_conjecture) and [Heron-Rota-Welsh conjecture](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/updates-and-plans-iii/) are the same one ?

Comment: Both of these (the first in 2014 and the second in 2017) are basically short notes in the *Notices* of the AMS.  Full proofs to be published later.  So I think we have to wait for those full proofs (if any actually appear eventually) before we can tell what the situation is.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar There is a full proof in a (60-page) paper by Adiprasito, Huh and Katz which has been on arxiv.org since 9 November 2015.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Indeed, it appears that they are not the same.